# C# HttpListener The format of the specified network name is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, http, exception, httplistener

I have this tiny piece of code where I try to add prefixes for my `HttpListener`:

```
listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.0.108:8088/");
listener.Start();
```

Which throws:

> System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): The format of the specified network name is not valid

I've tried everything: turning off firewall, running as administrator, registering given URL with `netsh http urlacl` and yet, nothing has worked so far.

I checked with `netstat` if that address is open to use and it is.
The weird thing about this is that I have been using this address for a long time until *Windows 10 Fall Creators Update*, since this update, only `localhost` is working.

Is there anything else that I forgot about or might try?

Comment: Errors starting with 0x8 are invalid pointer or addresses.    A listener can only be on local PC.  So is the IP address of your pc 192.168.0.108?

Comment: No, I checked that and my PC address is different, maybe another device in local network?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably forgot to configure your system to listen for `HTTP` protocol communication coming from the specified IP address. Try running the following command to include it:

```
netsh http add iplisten 192.168.0.108
```

Once this is done, check the list of the addresses (in which your IP should now appear):

```
netsh http show iplisten
```

and then try to run your code again.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot! I've changed my server's code to localhost prefix, but I also changed the client requests address to 192.168.0.108 and it works! Perfect!