# C# HttpListener exception: The format of the specified network name is not valid

Tags: c#, http, network-programming, network-protocols, httplistener

I am using this sample code to listen for HTTP requests:

```
// Create a listener.
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
// Add the prefixes.
listener.Prefixes.Add("some URI");

listener.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Listening...");

HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

listener.Stop();
```

But I am having very tough time, because I have no clue what prefix supposed to be. I have read the documentation on this, but whatever I try to enter there, whether it's URI of my computer or t's URI of machine that I am expecting to get response from, I always get exception:

> The format of the specified network name is not valid

I tried multiple things, one of them was that I specified URI of my own PC and got exception that these location is unreachable. The more I research the more lost I get.

In the MSDN example on `HttpListener` I see that URI supposed to have also a port, but if it has to be the URI of external machine I am listening to, then how can I know the port?

Also, I opened ports in firewall (using Windows tools, not commander). I even turned Windows firewall off, but didn't change anything.

My knowledge on networks is very limited, thus I don't even know the exact question I should ask.

I tried hints from related posts, such as:

[C# HttpListener The format of the specified network name is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47969786/c-sharp-httplistener-the-format-of-the-specified-network-name-is-not-valid)

but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example use:

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:9998/");
listener.Prefixes.Add("https://*:9999/");
```

If you use * listener will bind to all interfaces. You will need to run as administrator for it to register.

Now if you run this program on host which has a configured IP for example  192.168.178.39

You should connect using:
http://192.168.178.39:9998
https://192.168.178.39:9999

for SSL to work you will need to use the following command:

netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9999 certhash=Thumbprint appid={GUID}

> In the MSDN example on HttpListener I see that URI supposed to have
>   also a port, but if it has to be the URI of external machine I am
>   listening to, then how can I know the port?

In that case you should use the default port http 80 or https 443. You will need to use a local IP though on the machine for the prefix do **NOT** specify the external IP.

If the network has NAT then configure the firewall to allow traffic on port 443 and 80 to desired host.
Now you can connect using external ip and default ports.

Comment: Although it didn't fully answered my question, together with other posts helped me understand it. Thanks :)