# Intercept browser request from C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an Angular 7 application that need to send data to a fiscal cash printer installed on a client computer.Angular application is on a hosting server not locally

a simple working solution: Angular application sends current operation ID to hosting server and it is written in a QUEUE table
 a local c# app sends requests on every 4 seconds and check QUEUE table,if any waiting record ID is found then send data to a fiscal cash printer.
then delete current ID printed
 that seems to work but a problem here is that C# app sends a lot of requests(one at every 4 seconds) so I'm looking for an optimal solution

another one is to intercept browser request by C# app,using  `HttpListener`

```
  var web = new HttpListener();
        web.Prefixes.Add("http://94.237.00.111:80/");
        web.Start();
```

but even I added server ip

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=94.237.00.111:80
```

got this error

> System.Net.HttpListenerException: 'The format of the specified network
>   name is invalid'

tried that,but no fix: [C# HttpListener The format of the specified network name is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47969786/c-sharp-httplistener-the-format-of-the-specified-network-name-is-not-valid)

thanks for a fix or any another good solution!

Comment: `ipaddress=http://94.237.00.111:80` is not a valid IP address. Have you tried `netsh http add iplisten 94.237.00.111`?

Comment: http is a protocol and not part of a network name so you do not need http.

Comment: above IP is not the real one.You're right I've added 94.237.00.111:80.I can see it with 'netsh http show iplisten' but the same error.thanks

Comment: The port number is also not part of an IP address.

Comment: with or without port,the problem is the same

Comment: Is this IP address owned by that machine?  You can't bind to an IP address not recognized by the network cards of the system.  The way the question reads, you're trying to listen to traffic sent to another system.  That's not going to work.

Comment: That IP belongs to remote server,Angular app sends request from local computer,isn't it?Using localhost IP 127.0.0.1 seems to work.I think I'll send also a fake request to it to trigger.It is possible to use HttpListener like FileSystemWatcher,the application can do anything else during the watch?